# custom order titles takes too long

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

```
CREATE TABLE `arts` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 `title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_croatian_ci NOT NULL,
 `story` text COLLATE utf8mb4_croatian_ci NOT NULL,
 `status` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_croatian_ci NOT NULL,
 `tags` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_croatian_ci NOT NULL,
 `ind` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=30 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_croatian_ci
```

For example - a list of titles given from a mysql db.
I don't want to sort them by `date` or by `name` but need a custom sort.
Obviously I have a column named `ind` (means - index) as integer type, and after moving titles up and down on client side I do the following:

**js**

```
let ids = $.map($('.title'), (e) => $(e).data('id')).join(',');
let indexes = $.map($('.title'), (e) => $(e).index()).join(',');
$.post('index-pro.php', {fn: 'btn_save', args: [ids, indexes]}, function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

**index-pro.php**

```
function btn_save($ids, $indexes){
    global $db;
    $ids = explode(',', $ids);
    $indexes = explode(',', $indexes);
    $sql = "update arts set ind = :aind where id = :aid";
    $st = $db->prepare($sql);
    foreach($ids as $key=>$val){
        $st->execute([
            ":aid" => $val,
            ":aind" => $indexes[$key]
        ]);
    }
}
```

So my next call with a custom order will be:

```
select id, title from arts order by ind asc
```

This all works but with a serious problem - performances. With a thousand of titles the job will take about 14 seconds on server side.

Is there any more native way to do this?
Maybe creating a file with a custom ordered titles and somehow using it or... I have no idea.

Any help?

Comment: What is your table structure? include `SHOW CREATE TABLE arts` output in your question. A database index on `ind` is all that should be required. I'm assuming your query will have a limit (not returning all resuts)?

Comment: @danblack, I did

Comment: Doh, sorry. need more coffee.

Comment: Not your current issue BUT you can move the `prepare` and SQL construction outside the `foreach` loop. Just `execute` in the loop.

Comment: @user3783243, I see you point but not sure how to do this, pls example. In fact this may be the main problem

Comment: How many elements are you updating in this loop? Have all them changed? Can you use a js onchange script to limit the results to changed items. On prepare the `$sql = ...` and `$st =` will go before the `foreach ...` loop.

Comment: @user3783243 - I move the two lines from the loop. Result - slightly faster, but... not as a real solution.

Comment: @danblack - I move the two lines from the loop. Result - slightly faster, but... not as a real solution. If one single title is moved up or down - means that all other titles must be updated, because they are pushed up or down.

Comment: Try wrapping the loop in transaction - https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#transactions (not sure if  this is the same nodejs library), but single `begin` before the loop, and `commit` after the loop is finished.

Comment: @user3783243 - in that case, without `ind` column - how to save custom order arranged on client side?

Comment: Oh, misread the `custom sort` part. Alternative approach, increment all records greater than the new/updated one by 1, and all less then decrease by 1? e.g. 3 updates instead of 1k+

Comment: @user3783243 - hmm... means each time all rows will be updated, what is the difference?

Comment: Personally I'd just remove the `ind` column and manage ordering of the posts in a different table

Comment: You ask 'what's the difference?' The difference is executing 1 query instead of a thousand. It will be orders of magnitude faster.

Comment: @kerbholz, pls an example

Comment: @Strawberry, pls an example